# Bash for loop that removes files without suffixes from multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash

I have 5000 directories that need cleaning. I want to run a script that removes files without a suffix and keep those with any suffix. I know that all files without a suffix can be safely removed because these directories contain images of various types. I've tried this:

```
for i in $(ls -d */)
do 
  rm $i !(*.*)
done
```

I get a syntax error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
`  rm $i !(*.*)'
```

I really don't want to repeat that process 5000 times. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First this is very dangerous.. Second, please add an example on what is the suffix that you want to remove form all these files..

Comment: `!(*.*)` is an extglob expression. That feature is off until/unless you enable it explicitly, as with `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Also, [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: ...consider `find . -type f -mindepth 2 ! -name '*.*' -delete`.

Comment: ...also, `rm $i !(*.*)` is different from `rm "$i"/!(*.*)`, which seems more likely to be what you're intending to write (though that, like your original code, requires extglob support to be enabled before it'll run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't iterate over the output of `ls`. It is extremely risky, error-prone and strongly discouraged by the authors. Also, if you just want to find files and delete them, the `find` utility will do that a lot more efficiently.

The most basic version would be:

```
$ find . -mindepth 2 -type f ! -name "*.*" -delete
```

This is efficient because you won't start 5000 processes of `rm` (one for each directory). In fact, this is just one process. `find` will call `unlink()` to remove the file as it finds it.